# Ubuntu Server 20.10 - Errors for Apache2 installation

Tags: apt, server, apache2

I am following this [guide](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-apache#2-installing-apache) for Apache2 installation.
My Understanding: Is that this is meant for 'Ubuntu 16.04 LTS', however i could not find any guide for Ubuntu Server 20.10, so i thought i could give it a try...

2nd Step-A : run `$sudo apt update`;

> Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease 
> Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease 
> Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease 
> Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease 
> Reading package lists... Done 
> Building dependency tree 
> Reading state information... Done 
> 42 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list ---upgradable' to see them.

2nd Step-B: run `$sudo apt install apache2`;

> Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. 
> See "systemct1 status apache2.service" and "journalct1 -xe" for details. 
> invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "start" failed.

What am i doing wrong?

Update#1; So i tried to do `sudo systemctl status apache2.service` the response are...

> apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server 
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) 
> Active: Failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-01-26 18:01:40; 77ms ago 
> Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ 
> Process: 618874 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachect1 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

The Errors stated that...

> apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE 
> apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. 
> Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.

Comment: Please add the full output of `udo apt install apache2`

Comment: I think the message is a failure when apache tries to start and fails. But without more information nobody can help. Take a look at the apache error log probably `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and/or run `sudo systemctl status apache2.service`. Edit your question with that information.

Comment: Ok, i have updated the rest information into it... thanks for the heads up @codlord.

Comment: I added the full output for the step 2-B. Thanks for reminding me! @Soren A

Comment: systemctl  endsin the letter "l" not the digit "1" ... anyway you have an error in the apache configuration. Look in the apache error log amd findout what the problem is.

Comment: how can i find the error log? What is the command to enter the fix for the error in the apache2.conf? @Soren A

Comment: Take a look at the apache error log `/var/log/apache2/error.log`